# React Js - Not understanding the render and re-renders for this code in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

```
import { useState,useReducer } from 'react'

const countReducer = (state,newState)=>({...state,...newState})

function Counter({initialCount = 0, step = 1}) {

  const [me,setMe] = useState('ABc');

  const [state, setState] = useReducer(countReducer,{
    count:initialCount
  })

  const count = state.count

  let i=5;
  console.log('i->'+i)
    const changeVal = ()=>{
    console.log('curre val '+me)
    console.log('i val inside**'+i)
    i=i+1
    setMe('pqrts'+i)
  }
  console.log('i->after '+i)
  console.log('next val '+me)


  const increment = () => setState({count:count+step})
  return <>
  <button onClick={changeVal}>Change the alphabets: {me}</button>
  <button onClick={increment}>{count}</button>
  </>
}
```

I am calling the Counter function in App component. When I click on the change the alphabets first time, I am getting 'pqrts6', then when I click on the button 2 times, I will get 'pqrts7', then if i again click , i will get the 'pqrts6'

I have tried adding console logs but I'm still unable to understand the behavior.

If my understanding is correct, react should persist the values of local variables and I should always get 'pqrts6'
`

Comment: Maybe due to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20817